# How to iterate through objects within array in Lodash

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash within an HTML template for an email in Node.js. I have one array with several objects. I would like to iterate through each object and list all of the repeating values. When I use the code below, I receive an error stating that the value is undefined (e.g., `ReferenceError: firstName is not defined`). The HTML template is in a separate file.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Javascript:

```
var template = fs.readFileSync('server/views/email-template.html').toString();
var htmlAll = _.template(template)(orderInfo);
```

HTML:

```
<% _.forEach(function(firstName) { %><%- firstName %></td><% }); %> <% _.forEach(function(lastName) { %><%- lastName %></td><% }); %>
<% _.forEach(function(address) { %><%- address %></td><% });%>
<% _.forEach(function(city) { %><%- city %><% }); %>, <% _.forEach(function(state.code) { %><%- state.code %><% });
%> <% _.forEach(function(zip) { %><%- zip %><% }); %>

<% _.forEach(function(item) { %><td><%- item %></td><% }); %>
<% _.forEach(function(cost) { %><td><%- cost %></td><% }); %>
```

Array:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": "123 Broadway",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": {
      "code": "NY",
      "state": "New York"
    },
    "zip": "10001",
  },

  {
    "color": "White",
    "size": "M",   
    "item": "T-Shirt",
    "cost": 19.99,
  },
  {
    "color": "Blue",
    "size": "L",   
    "item": "T-Shirt",
    "cost": 19.99,
  }
]
```

Comment: Are these templates EJS? If so, please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @m01 no that's just underscore.js templates

Answer (score 18):

There are couple of things wrong here actually. Starting with template syntax, you are only specifying the iterator to foreach in your template but we need data and iterator both something as follows

```
_.forEach(users, function(user){
```

Also you have multiple objects in single array position so I have update the json structure a little bit as well.

After minor updates template something like this with some property missing intentionally,

```
var tmpl = _.template('<ul><% _.forEach(users, function(user) { %><li><%- user.firstName %></li><li><%- user.address %></li><li><%- user.state.code %></li><li><%- user.state.state %></li><ol> <% _.forEach(user.orders, function(order) { %> <li><span><%- order.item %><span> cost is: <span><%- order.cost %><span></li> <% }); %> </ol> <% }); %></ul>');
```

and json with orders arrays in same object is as follows

```
var data = { 'users': 

        [
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": "123 Broadway",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": {
      "code": "NY",
      "state": "New York"
    },
    "zip": "10001",
    "orders": [
        {
            "color": "White",
            "size": "M",   
            "item": "T-Shirt",
            "cost": 19.99,
        },
        {
            "color": "Blue",
            "size": "L",   
            "item": "Pant",
            "cost": 19.99,
        }
  ]  
  } 
]
};
```

You can see it working on here at [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/wohuwejiqo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Is it necessary to change the json structure in order for this to work?

Comment: no it isn't but I am not sure how you can have multiple objects at single array position, If that's possible I will be happy to know. Other thing you can do is create a one big object with named objects in it but again you never know how many objects a single order can contain

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in ES6 arrow function style:

`const users = ['Jack', 'Jill'];
_.forEach(users, user => {console.log(user);});`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you give `orderInfo[0]` to your template. And in your array, `orderInfo[0]` is just this part :

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": "123 Broadway",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": {
      "code": "NY",
      "state": "New York"
    },
    "zip": "10001",
}
```

So the template can't iterate on the missing values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But I must be doing something else wrong as well. Because when I remove the `[0]` nothing is displayed for the item and cost values.

Comment: If you remove tne [0] you are giving the entire array to your template so you have to change your template

Comment: I've updated my template but I'm still not able to iterate through and get the respective values. Any suggestions?